# Python 3 Newbie Question: Is this code efficient / clean? Can it improve / simplify

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

payout calculation prompt based on hours worked and rate per hour, where hours above 40 are paid out at 1.5x the original rate.

Test at 45 hours at 10.50 per hour. the output should be the payout figures.

[image: code]

Comment: Images of code are useless. Unless you're using a graphics editor to write code, you already have it as text in a code editor, and that's what should be posted here  - code, in text form, properly indented and formatted so it's readable. See [ask] and [mcve]. Also, if you have working code that you're just looking to have reviewed, you should be posting on [codereview.se] instead; that site exists for just that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would organize the code in a different way. 1. Functions to package up pieces of code so they can be reused and parametrized. 2. Exception handling to indicate incorrect user input.

```
def get_hrs_rph_from_user():

    while True:
        hrs = input('Enter Hours: ')
        try:
            hrs = int(hrs)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Cannot convert [{}] into integer'.format(hrs))

    while True:
        rph = input('Enter Rate per Hour: ')
        try:
            rph = float(rph)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Cannot convert [{}] into float'.format(rph))

    return hrs, rph


def calculate_payout(hrs, rph, hrs_norm=40, coeff=1.5):

    if hrs <= hrs_norm:
        return hrs * rph
    else:
        return hrs_norm * rph + (hrs - hrs_norm) * coeff * rph


if __name__ == '__main__':

    payout = calculate_payout(*get_hrs_rph_from_user())
    print('\nCalculated payout = {}'.format(payout))
```

Another version of the very same code based on the suggestion by @Jeronimo (pretty complicated and error-prone way for the one who new in python):

```
def get_from_user_factory(config):

    ans = dict()

    for key, elem in config.items():
        def get_from_user(line=elem['input_line'], type_=elem['value_type']):
            while True:
                value = input('{}: '.format(line))
                try:
                    return type_(value)
                except ValueError:
                    print(
                        'Cannot convert [{}] into {}'
                        .format(value, type_.__name__))
        ans[key] = get_from_user

    return ans


def calculate_payout(hrs, rph, hrs_norm=40, coeff=1.5):

    if hrs <= hrs_norm:
        return hrs * rph
    else:
        return hrs_norm * rph + (hrs - hrs_norm) * coeff * rph


if __name__ == '__main__':

    input_config = {
        'hrs': {'input_line': 'Enter Hours', 'value_type': int},
        'rph': {'input_line': 'Enter Rate per Hour', 'value_type': float}}

    input_functions = get_from_user_factory(input_config)

    input_data = {key: func() for key, func in input_functions.items()}
    print('\nData from user: {}'.format(input_data))

    payout = calculate_payout(**input_data)
    print('Calculated payout = {}'.format(payout))
```

Comment: You could additionally make a function `input_type` or so with a prompt and a datatype (`int`, `float`, ..) as arguments. I wonder if there's even a builtin library in Python for that.

Comment: @Jeronimo Yes, code inside `get_hrs_rph_from_user()` is repeated twice. Not a big deal I guess. Common workaround is to use dictionaries to specify parameters for every roll `input_config = [{'input_line': 'Enter Hours', 'value_type': int}, {'input_line': 'Enter Rate per Hour', 'value_type': float}]` and iterate inside `get_from_user()` or create a new function for every element in `input_config`.